# html emails - move elements down the page?

Tags: html, css

I am working on an html email, and i have a really simple element (`ul`) that i want to move down the page.

I checked [campaign monitor's guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and the support is not there for negative margins, or the `position: absolute` parent / `position: relative` child, the 2 main ways i'd generally move an element down an html page, so neither of those would work.

Might be a dumb question...but what is the best way to simply move an element down the html email template like you would on a normal html page?

Comment: You could do 'hidden' block level elements with a height above your `ul` to push down your content. A lot of templates are still built with tables so you could give a `tr` before your content `tr` a height to mock moving your content down.

Answer (score 2):

When coding HTML emails, you generally have to do things that are considered bad practice on the web.

Here are some techniques I've used in production:

- If your `ul` is within an `tr`, create a sibling `tr` and set the height of that `tr`'s `td` equal to the spacing that you need.
- Use one or more `<br />` to push elements down.
- Use `margin` or `padding` (not as compatible as the two methods above)